# Why isnt William of Orange considered to have conquered England?

Tags: england

I've always heard, colloquially, that the last successful invasion of England was in 1066. It seems to me that William of Orange, although the grandson of Charles I, was Dutch. It also seems like he invaded England and took the throne from the House of Stuart.

Comment: Because he was invited in by the [English Parliament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glorious_Revolution).

Comment: and he never incorporated Britain into his own dominions, it remained an independent entity. Otherwise the Brits would all be speaking Dutch now ;)

Comment: This seems to be a valid question to me. There should be a better defined reason for closure.

Comment: From the Wikipedia article on [William III of England](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_III_of_England#Invasion_of_England): "William is the last person to successfully invade England by force of arms."

Comment: This rag says there has been [70 invasions](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2380652/The-false-idea-fortress-Britain-How-nation-invaded-scores-times-Norman-invasion-1066.html) since 1066. Perhaps update the question to be about the Myth?

Comment: Because the British liked him. Otherwise they would not call this invasion the Glorious revolution.

Comment: All fair enough.  Clearly, however, not all the British liked him as there was some fighting.  I like the answer pointing out that William didn't incorporate England into another empire as a distinction.

Comment: @Steve This needs to be unlocked. It's not about trivia or basic facts, it's about supporting or debunking a conventional interpretation of the Glorious Revolution.